# How to write array data to json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to write the data that the loop passes to the array "eventsPolygon", to json. This array returns 4 args. With this method, I get the error "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined"

```
async function main() {
  console.log("Start checking rewards")
  const currentBlockNumberPolygon = await maticProvider.getBlockNumber() - 1
  const currentBlockNumberBsc = await bscProvider.getBlockNumber() - 1

  const oldestBlockNumberPolygon = 22939848
  const oldestBlockNumberBsc = 13763979


  const eventFilterPolygon = Missions.filters.RewardToPay()
  const eventFilterBsc = Rewards.filters.RewardPayed()

  let eventsPolygon = []
  let eventsBsc = []

  for (let i = oldestBlockNumberPolygon; i < currentBlockNumberPolygon - 10000; i += 10000) {
    const eventsLoop = await Missions.queryFilter(eventFilterPolygon, i, i + 10000)
    eventsPolygon = eventsPolygon.concat(eventsLoop)

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(eventsPolygon);
    fs.writeFile('eventsBsc.json', jsonData.finished)

    console.log(i)
  }

  //for(let i = oldestBlockNumberBsc; i < currentBlockNumberBsc-10000; i+=10000) {
  //const eventsLoop = await Rewards.queryFilter(eventFilterBsc, i, i+10000)
  // eventsBsc = eventsBsc.concat(eventsLoop)
  //console.log(i)
  //}

  console.log('a')
}
```

Comment: Which line is getting that error>?

Comment: You're overwriting the `eventsBsc.json` file each time through the loop.

Comment: I change it to: 
       function finished (error) {
         console.log("error");
       }
       
       const jsonData = eventsPolygon.toString();
       fs.writeFile('eventsBsc.json', jsonData, finished)

Comment: and now its writing an "object" into json

Comment: `jsonData` is a JSON string, it should write that string into the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` returns a string representation of your JSON. So you cannot do this:

```
fs.writeFile('eventsBsc.json', jsonData.finished)
```

Simply write `jsonData` to the file:

```
await fs.writeFile('eventsBsc.json', jsonData);
```

Be aware that this function is async. You need to `await` it

Comment: Scripts write this datas, but at the end its not save them. How to repair that?

Comment: by default this will overwrite the file. You need to specify append flag like this. `fs.writeFile('eventsBsc.json', jsonData, {flag: 'a'})`